# Не получается установить стили, чтобы список выводился поверх другого элемента

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Нужно чтобы раскрывающийся список ничего не смещал, в данном случае это другой input со списком. Мой код:

```js
var lesson = ["matematika","russkiy","fizika","i t.d."];
var course = [1,2,3,4,5];

$("div.body_list").next("#list_rasp").hide();
    
 $("div.body_list").each(function(){
  
  if($(this).next().html()==""){ 
   console.log(111);
   var teg = [];                                                                                                                        
   var name_table = ($(this).find("input").attr("name").substr(6));
   
   $.each(eval(name_table), function(i){
    var val = eval(name_table)[i];
    teg[i] = "<div id='"+val+"' class='list_rasp'>"+val+"</div>"   
   });
   
   $(this).next().html(teg);
   
   reset();
   checking();
   
  }; 
  
 });
  
  function checking(){ 
  $(document).on("click", "div#list_rasp div.list_rasp", function(e){  $("div#list_rasp").has(this).prev().find("input").val($(this).html());
  });
  };

 function reset(){ 
  $(document).on("click", "div.body_list input", function(e){
   $(this).val("");
  });
 }; 

 function turnUp(this_arr){
  this_arr.html('&#9660;');
  $("div.body_list").has(this_arr).next().slideUp(200);
 };
   
 function turnDown(this_arr){
  $("div.array").html('&#9660;');
  $("div#list_rasp").slideUp(200);
  this_arr.html('&#9650;');
  $("div.body_list").has(this_arr).next().slideDown(200);
 }; 
 
 $(document).on("click", ".array", function(e){
  if($("div.body_list").has(this).next().is(":hidden")){
   turnDown($(this));
  }else{
   turnUp($(this));
  }; 
 });

 function search(this_in){
  setTimeout(function(){
   
   var index = 0;
   var mass = [];
   var srch_list = [];
   var name_table2 = this_in.attr("name").substr(6);   
   var srch_name = this_in.val(); 
    
   $.each(eval(name_table2), function(i){
    mass[i] = eval(name_table2)[i];
    var str = eval(mass[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(srch_name.toLowerCase()));
    if(str != -1){    
     srch_list[index] = "<div class='list_rasp' id='"+mass[i]+"'>"+mass[i]+"</div>";
     index++;
    };
   });
   
   $("div.body_list").has(this_in).next().html(srch_list);
   
   if($("div.body_list").has(this_in).next().is(":hidden") && srch_name != ""){
    this_arr2 = this_in.next();
    turnDown(this_arr2);
   };
   
   checking();
   
  }, 50);
 }; 
  
 $("div.body_list input").focus(function(){
  
  this_in = eval($(this));
  
  if($("div.body_list").has(this).next().is(":hidden")){
   $("div.array").html('&#9660;');
   $("div#list_rasp").slideUp(200);
  };
    
  $("div.body_list input").keyup(function(eventObject){
   
   if(eventObject.key == "Shift" || 
    eventObject.key == "Control") {
    return false
   } else {
    search(this_in);
   };
   // keypress не определяется смартфонами, потому keyup
  });
 });
```

```css
div.body_list{
  width: 258px; height: 50px; padding: 1px;
  box-shadow: 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15),
              0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15),
              -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15),
              0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 2px; /* не работает с border и outline */
}

div.body_list input[name^='value_']{
  width: 208px; height: 48px; /* padding-left: 16px; */
  border: none;
  padding: 0; margin: 0; top: 0; left: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;  
  font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px; line-height: 0;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

div.body_list div.array{
  width: 48px; height: 48px; float: right;
  text-align: center; line-height: 48px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9); color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  cursor: pointer;
} .array:hover{
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  color: inherit;
}

div#list_rasp{
  width: 256px; height: auto; max-height: 240px; 
  margin: 2px 0 0 1px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto !important;
}

div.list_rasp{
  width: 100%; height: 48px;
  padding: 0 8px 0 16px;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  line-height: 48px;
  overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
} div.list_rasp:hover{
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); 
  box-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body_list">
  <input type="text" name="value_course">
  <div class="array">&#9660;</div>
</div>
<div id="list_rasp"></div>
      
<div class="body_list">
  <input type="text" name="value_lesson">
  <div class="array">&#9660;</div>
</div>
<div id="list_rasp"></div>
```

И прошу пожалуйста не кидать  код типа:

```
style {
    position:relative;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

я так пробовал, он всё равно смещается вместе со списком, а не остаётся под ним

Comment: не размещайте ссылки на исполнители кода, воспользуйтесь сниппетом в редактировании вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы реализовал так:

1. Ваш блок со списком (выпадающий) поместил бы в конец блока, находящегося перед ним (в котором поле ввода и стрелка).
2. У нашего родительского блока `position: relative;`.
3. У выпадающего блока установил стили:

   ```
   position: absolute;
   top: 100%;
   ```